# props to options react apollo

Tags: javascript, frontend, reactjs

Нужно передать userID которая поступает в компонент из вне через props в переменную в запросе USER_QUERY. Приведенный ниже пример не работает, как все таки правильно это сделать?

```
@compose(
    connect(({ locale, common: { gameID } }) => ({ locale, gameID })),
    graphql(USER_QUERY, {
        options: ({ userID, gameID }) => ({ userID, gameID })
    }),
    ...
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
  graphql<Query, OwnProps>(DATA_QUERY, {
    options: props => ({
      variables: {
        id: props.id,
      },
    }),
  }),
```